# DB2 to MySQL Migration (stored procedures, functions, triggers)

Tags: mysql, db2, migration, database-migration

Is there any way or tools to migrate tables, stored procedures, views, data, functions and triggers from **DB2 to MySQL**?

I have tried some tools but it can only migrate tables and data.

Do I have to do it separately for (tables, data, views) and (stored procedures, functions, triggers)?

Comment: You might have more luck asking in dba.stackexchange.com. Everything that is beyond the simple stuff requires manual work or at least review and testing. It is one of the reasons why migrations are not succeeding.

Comment: The syntax differs, and the difference is critical. I doubt that SP/Fn/triggers may be migrated automatically.

Comment: google your friend :) you should find tool to migrate table and data, but you need to rewrite your procedures and functions, and trigger. PS: it is better to use PGSQL